# Using Eclipse for Fortran

Tags: fortran, photran

I have a brief question here about how to setup Eclipse for Fortran.

I have already downloaded "Photran" (the Fortran tool for Eclipse) and installed it.  The problem I'm having is that every time I try to run a program I get a message that says `"Launch failed.  Binary not found."`  Then, I found out you have to "build" the file first, so when I tried to do that, I got a message in the console that says the following:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Fortran2 ****

make all 
/bin/sh: gfortran: command not found
Building file: ../Src/helloworld.f90
make: *** [Src/helloworld.o] Error 127
Invoking: GNU Fortran Compiler
gfortran -funderscoring -I/usr/locl/bin -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "Src/helloworld.o" "../Src/helloworld.f90"

**** Build Finished ****
```

Does anybody have any pointers on how to get this working?

Comment: Have you confirmed that gfortran is installed correctly?

Comment: Yes, gfortran works just fine if I invoke it from the terminal.  What's weird, however, is this line:

"/bin/sh: gfortran: command not found".  gfortran is not located in that directory on my computer...it's in "/usr/local/bin".  So that has to be part of the problem, I just don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: /bin/sh isn't a directory. It's the shell interpreter that is calling gfortran. Maybe the sh shell can't find gfortran in its path - but I'm just guessing here. You could try running /bin/sh in a terminal, then see if you can invoke gfortran.

Comment: It could be that `/usr/local/bin` is not in the `PATH` passed to subshells, started by Eclipse. Or you've misconfigured Photran - the include path in `-I/usr/locl/bin` seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 3):

Are you on OSX?

If so I found the problem is that OSX does not pass the PATH variable to applications started through the GUI. So to get around this one should start eclipse from the terminal. This worked when I had the problem.

There is a way to set the path for GUI launched applications explained here, though I didn't follow this myself. http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/08/setting-path-osx-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 2):

```
ln -s /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran
```

This did the trick for me. Photran/Eclipse is now running with gfortran without complaints.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install gcc-gfortran which you should be able to find with your package manager.

The gcc-gfortran package provides "gfortran" which is what actually compiles FORTRAN (at least it does on Fedora).

Answer (score 1):

The link method did not work for me in OSX 10.12.1 Sierra, but launching Eclipse from the Terminal does work (assuming that Eclipse.app is in Applications, type `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse` in the Terminal).

Comment: Do not use "above link". There is no link above your answer just now. The answers can and do move around.